# Java: Where to pinpoint NullPointerException during client-server socket connection? (with GUI)

Tags: java, sockets

this is my first question here in stackoverflow. I am trying to create a socket connection between the client and the server (this application has GUI components). Here's the planned flow:

```
1. start 'MultiServer'              // this frame has a related class file named 'MultiServerThread'
2. start 'LogIn'                    // when this frame is opened for the first time, it successfully establishes connection to the 'MultiServer'
3. from 'LogIn', go to 'SignUp'     // I want to know how to end the connection from 'LogIn'
4. from 'SignUp, go back to 'LogIn' // when this frame is opened again, it now throws Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0"
```

However, the error starts when I go back to the LogIn (as well as starting frames other than LogIn) and trying to make a query (out.writeObject(value)) to the server.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
at client.LogIn.submitData(LogIn.java:461)
at client.LogIn.setReaction(LogIn.java:255)
at client.LogIn.lambda$new$0(LogIn.java:241)
at client.LogIn$$Lambda$13/1313922862.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2022)
at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(AbstractButton.java:2346)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(DefaultButtonModel.java:402)
at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(DefaultButtonModel.java:259)
at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(BasicButtonListener.java:252)
at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Component.java:6525)
at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(JComponent.java:3321)
at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Component.java:6290)
at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Container.java:2234)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Component.java:4881)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2292)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Container.java:4898)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Container.java:4533)
at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Container.java:4462)
at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Container.java:2278)
at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Window.java:2739)
at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Component.java:4703)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:746)
at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:97)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:697)
at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(EventQueue.java:691)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:86)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:719)
at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(EventQueue.java:717)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(ProtectionDomain.java:75)
at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:716)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:116)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:105)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:101)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:93)
at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:82)
```

Here is my code for the LogIn (code trimmed to relevant parts only). It points to three lines of my code; ActionListener getEvent..., submitData(String) try statement, and setReaction(ActionEvent) else if statement:

```
package client;

import ...;

public class LogIn extends JFrame implements KeyListener {

public LogIn() {
    initComponents();
    ....
} 

// PROTECTED BLOCKS

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                   
private void initComponents() { .... }                              

// USER-GENERATED BLOCKS

private String QueryType, Username, Password, ServerResponse;
private ObjectOutputStream out;
private ObjectInputStream in;
private Socket socket;

ActionListener getEvent = (ActionEvent eventEmergence) -> {  setReaction(eventEmergence); }; // <EXCEPTION POINTS HERE>

private void setReaction(ActionEvent eventEncountered) {
    if (eventEncountered.getSource() == BT_Register) { 
        openSignUp();
        this.dispose();
    } 
    else if (eventEncountered.getSource() == BT_Login || eventEncountered.getSource() == TF_Password) {             
        submitData(eventEncountered.getActionCommand()); // <EXCEPTION POINTS HERE>
    }
    ....
}

private void validateChar(KeyEvent evt) { .... }

// FRAME CREATION BLOCKS

private void openSignUp() {
    SignUp SFW = new SignUp();
    SFW.setVisible(true); 
    this.dispose();
}

private void openBallot(String StudentID, String StudentName, String Section) { .... }

private void openAccessDenied() { .... }

private void openAuthenticationFailure() { .... }

private void openInfoDev() { .... }

private void openInfoSys() { .... }

// KEY LISTENER METHOD OVERRIDE BLOCKS

@Override public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) { .... }

@Override public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) { .... }

@Override public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) { .... }

// CONNECTION-RELATED BLOCKS

private void initConnection() throws IOException {
    try { 
        socket = new Socket("localhost", 7555);
        out = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream()); // send
        out.flush();
        in = new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream()); // receive
        translateResponse();
    }
    catch (UnknownHostException e) { .... } 
    catch (IOException e) { .... }
    endConnection();
}

private void endConnection() throws IOException {
    out.close();
    in.close();
    socket.close();
}

private void translateResponse() throws IOException {
    do {
        try {
            ServerResponse = (String)in.readObject(); // receive server response
            // determine action based from server response
            if (ServerResponse.equals("Accepted")) {
                String StudentID   = (String)in.readObject();
                String StudentName = (String)in.readObject();
                String Section     = (String)in.readObject();
                openBallot(StudentID, StudentName, Section);
            }
            else if (ServerResponse.equals("AccountAlreadyVoted")) {
                openAccessDenied();
            }
            else if (ServerResponse.equals("IncorrectData")) {
                openAuthenticationFailure();
            }
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException e) { }
    }
    while (!ServerResponse.equals("connection.terminate"));
}

private void submitData(String idle) {
    QueryType = "Login";
    Username = TF_Username.getText(); // get Username string
    Password = TF_Password.getText(); // get Password string
    try {
        out.writeObject(QueryType); // submit type of operation <EXCEPTION POINTS HERE>
        out.writeObject(Username); // send Username
        out.writeObject(Password); // send Password 
        out.flush();
    }
    catch(IOException e) { }
}

public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
    // create new LogIn
    LogIn LI = new LogIn();
    LI.setVisible(true);
    LI.initConnection();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The stack trace lists the calls that your program last executed in reverse order, so your program flow right before the exception is:

1. LogIn, line 241
2. LogIn, line 255
3. LogIn, line 461

And on line 461, `eventEncountered` is probably null. It would help to learn to use a debugger so that you can see where your variables are (not) getting set.

Comment: `And on line 461, eventEncountered is probably null.` .. line `461` is in method `submitData` and there is no `eventEncoutered` there.

Comment: @Silvan Yes, this line. `out` is `null` there. Try to find the reason for that. For example with the mentioned debugger. And as far as I see it, you don't need to call `LI.initConnection();` in the `main` method.

Comment: @Tom, I found what was missing when the LogIn is created from SignUp: `LI.initConnection();` But another problem arises, when a new LogIn is created, it only shows me this: http://s23.postimg.org/c9os4zaej/image.png

Comment: @Silvan You should call that method inside of your constructor, like you did with `initComponents`. This avoids problems like that. ... If you have another question, then ask a new question. You can link to this question if you like.

Comment: Thank you for giving me possible answers on my first question here in Stack Overflow. I have already solved my connection problem by taking an entirely different approach: use all of the frames in one separate main class. That way, the connection to the server doesn't get closed by the closing of the frames themselves.